# Thread Specific Data vs Thread Local Storage

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, thread-local-storage, thread-specific-storage

I've read Kerrisk's [The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272200), Chapter 31 on Threads. The chapter include Thread Specific Data (Section 31.3.4) and Thread Local Storage (Section 31.4). The topics were covered on pages 663-669.

Thread Specific Data (`pthread_key_create`, `pthread_setspecific`, `pthread_getspecific`, and friends) looks more powerful, but appears to be a little more cumbersome to use, and appears to use the memory manager more frequently.

Thread Local Storage (`__thread` on static and global declarations) looks a little less powerful since its limited to compile time, but its appears to be easier to use, and appears to stay out of the memory manager at runtime.

I could be wrong about the runtime memory manager since there could be code behind the scenes that calls `pthread_key_create` when it encounters `__thread` variables.

Kerrisk did not offer a compare/contrast of the two strategies, and he did not make a recommendation on when to use which in a given situation.

To add context to the question: I'm evaluating a 3rd party library. The library uses globals, does *not* utilize locking, and I want to use it in a multi-threaded program. The program uses threading to minimize network latencies.

Is there a hands down winner? Or are there different scenarios that warrant using one or the other?

Comment: Generally it is preferable to use neither. Why do you want to use this at all?

Comment: Thanks David. Its a network-based multi-threaded program to help maintain throughput in the faced of latencies. I want to try a 3rd party library for parsing, but the library uses static globals for state.

Comment: Hmm, messy. I can see where you are coming from. Ideal world has the information passed by parameter. Perhaps consider a more thread friendly library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `pthread_key_create` and friends are much older, and thus supported on more systems.

The `__thread` is a relative newcomer, is generally *much more convenient* to use, and ([according to Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) is supported on most POSIX systems that still matter: Solaris Studio C/C++, IBM XL C/C++, GNU C, Clang and Intel C++ Compiler (Linux systems).

The `__thread` also has a significant advantage that it is usable from signal handlers (with the exception of using `__thread` from `dlopen`ed shared library, see this [bug](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16133)), because its use does not involve `malloc` (with the same exception).

Comment: Also see https://blogs.oracle.com/seongbae/entry/pthread_get_set_specific_vs.  One limitation of `pthread_key_create()` is the calls are not guaranteed to return success always. That makes these calls unusable in `__init` type functions without making some assumptions. So, `__thread` is simple & guaranteed way of thread specific data.

Answer (score 1):

The pthread interfaces are POSIX standard, so they are more portable.  Use them if you intend to use the code on something besides a linux system.  On the other hand, if you are strictly on gcc/linux, then the __thread mechanism is certainly easier to use.  Just be aware that it is a gcc specific extension, and not supported on all platforms.

Comment: C++11 has a `thread_local` specifier that is similar to `__thread`, though, and this should eventually get supported everywhere.

Comment: `__thread` is *not* a GCC-specific extension -- it's supported by approximately all UNIX compilers that matter today.