# Reusing a global array in a function in a threadsafe way in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I want to use some temporary storage in a function and not have to reallocate it at each call.  This works fine for a single thread, but how do I extend the idea to multi-threaded programs (a subject I'm only familiar with in the abstract).

For example,

```
int *foo_array;
int foo_array_size;//global initalises to 0
void foo(int *A, int n){
  int i;
  if(n>foo_array_size && foo_array) free(foo_array);
  if(n>foo_array_size){
    foo_array=malloc(2*n*sizeof(int));
    foo_array_size=2*n;
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    foo_array[i]=A[i];
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    A[i]=foo_array[i];
  }
}
```

As I understand it, foo_array points to the same place in memory for every thread, so if foo() is called at the same time in two threads, we could end up with unexpected behaviour (correct?).

So how would I, at an abstract level, perhaps, ensure that foo_array points to different memory for use in each thread?

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015738/ ?

Comment: You have to design your code with "private pointers" one per thread. Just off the top of my head: using array of pointers, one element per thread. Same thing for size variable

Comment: Use an array of `int *` (`int *foo_array[]`). Pass the index that the thread should use on creation: `int pthread_create(..., ..., ..., &index)`.

Comment: Side note: you probably can avoid to continuously `free` and `malloc` new memory using `realloc` instead. Useful if data `A` array @ t-1 still the same @ t. If so pointers must be init to `NULL`;

Comment: Do you need an array for every thread or do you want multiple threads to operate on a single array safely? Former is quite simple using the strategy @FiddlingBits indicated. The second option is slightly more difficult for fixed sized arrays and much more difficult, if you want to incorporate the reallocation of the array.

Comment: One array for each thread, that is populated and used within each call to foo.  I think I understand the answers and comments now, thanks.  (actually, if the comments were combined with the answer, I would be able to accept)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say with thread library you are using. The C11 thread library has the qualifier `_Thread_local` that creates a variable that has a different incarnation per thread.

If you don't have C11 threads, some compiler extensions may provide a similar feature. E.g `gcc` has `__thread`.

According to the thread library that you are using there may also be a set of functions that simulate such a thing. C11 threads have the `tss_t` type (thread specific storage) and functions `tss_create` etc to deal with them.

Comment: I don't know anything about specific thread libraries, but if you expand on the concepts I might be able to select your answer.  LPs and Fiddling Bits' comments are understandable, but are they the same idea as using the thread library you are referring to?

Comment: @Alejandro, no their ideas are merely on how to implement such things yourself. You still don't tell us what your platform, OS, compiler ... is. Please amend your question accordingly.

Comment: There is no OS, platform, compiler or anything.  It's just a conceptual question :)

Comment: @Alejandro, in fact at least part of it is covered in the SO documentation for the "tag" C: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/topics